# Decoding 54 byte BMP without ImageIO

Tags: java, image

I have been trying to figure out how to decode an image BMP 54 bytes without using imageIO library. So far, my algorithm to loop the data after the 54 offset and my colorTable doesn't make any sense. Can someone gives me some hints to continue further? thx

```
static BufferedImage img = null;

private int biWidth;
private int biHeight;
private byte[][] colorTable ;

public ConcreteImage(File path) {
    super._path = path;
    try{
        FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream(super._path);
        int content;
        int count = 0 ;
        while ((content = f.read()) != -1) {

            if(count == 18)
                biWidth = content;

            if(count == 22)
                biHeight = content;

            if(count > 54){

                /*System.out.println(content);*/
                colorTable = new byte[biHeight][biWidth];
                while((content = f.read()) != -1){
                    byte rgb[] = new byte[content];
                    for(int n = 0; n <= biHeight; n++){
                        for(int j = 0; j <= biWidth; j++){
                            colorTable[n][j] = rgb[content]; //It points out that i have an error from there.
                            colorTable[n+1][j+1] = rgb[content+1];
                            colorTable[n+2][n+2] = rgb[content+2];

                        }
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(colorTable);


            }
            count++;

        }
        f.close();
```

Comment: You might want to consult the [BMP file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format).

Comment: What's biWidth and biHeight? What is `b` supposed to do? EDIT: Just realized biWidth is bufferedImageWidth, lol

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21927431/converting-encrypted-image-in-byte-to-bufferedimage-in-java-without-decrypting) link out.